# dse spark-submit : core not used when submitting a job (Running application "Cores = 0" with 3 workers available with 4 cores each)

Tags: apache-spark

I'm sending a job to my spark dse cluster composed of 3 workers with 4 cores each.

The job is correctly sent to my cluster, however Cores remain to zero and the job is waiting for ressources. The 3 workes are idle with 4 cores each. I don't understand why they don't get involved.

[See spark ui screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/h9yFe.png)

Job is sent using : `sudo -u cassandra dse spark-submit --master spark://XX.XX.XX.XXX:7077 --executor-cores=4 --total-executor-cores=4 --executor-memory=16g --class com.MyClass /home/spark.jar`

and gives me the following messages : `Initial job has not accepted any resources; check your cluster UI to ensure that workers are registered and have sufficient resources`

Nothing special in spark logs.
Any ideas ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You send the job with `--executor-memory=16g` but only have `8g` per worker.

Try to run it with `--executor-memory=8g` and you should be fine